# How to determine if two boolean expressions are the same

Tags: c#, boolean, boolean-logic

I need to determine if two different boolean expressions are the same. For example:

> S1 = a ∨ b 
>   S2 = (a ∧ ¬b) ∨ b;

these two are in fact the same. So I need to detect if they are the same. I am using C#.

Comment: the word 'why' springs to mind? Tell use the actual problem you are trying to solve...

Comment: do you mean, do two expressions obtain the same result?

Comment: That doesn't look like C#.  Do you mean `S1 = a | b`, `S2 = a&!b | b`, where `a` and `b` are booleans?

Comment: I've edited your question to use boolean algebra symbols since your notation was a bit confusing: "∨" for OR, "∧" for AND, and "¬" for NOT. I don't mean to step on your toes, though, so if that's confusing go ahead and undo my edit.

Comment: @MitchWheat I am trying to solve the exact same problem at the moment. I am building a custom reporting tool which allows the user to specify data filters to produce a chart. This chart can then be annotated. I need these annotations to apply to *that same chart* regardless of how the filters have been applied. So volume of records with Name='Sam' AND (Team=1 OR Team=2) is the same as (Team=1 OR Team=2) AND Name='Sam'. This is a very basic example. I think some kind of ordering system will be involved in the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I follow what you're asking...  If these are expressions using booleans (that is, the a and b in your example are booleans) you could work out the truth table for them, and if every case matches then your expressions are equivalent.

There are other ways but that seems fairly straight forward to implement.  Just plug in a=true, b=true; a=true, b=false; a=false b=true; a=false, b=false and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're really, *really* smart, and your problem contains millions of parameters, I'd say use brute force.

What you're doing is called "Formal equivalence checking", and is frequently done with a reduced ordered binary decision diagram, and at this point I'd be writing wikipedia articles, but since someone's gone to the trouble of doing that already, here they are.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_equivalence_checking

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram

... And I had no idea that the linq Expressions namespace existed. In which case, maybe I'd go with what Ivan said.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box way to do that. The closest you get is [`Expression.Reduce()`](http://127.0.0.1:47873/help/1-7260/ms.help?product=VS&productVersion=100&method=f1&query=System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Reduce&locale=en-US&category=DevLang:csharp%00TargetFrameworkMoniker:.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0) method, which doesn't do the reduction you want.

You will need to write an expression parser that simplifies, say boolean expressions, and then some logic to verify that the simplified expressions are the same.

Example class (no verification, just the framework of getting the expressions in:

```
public class ExpressionTest {
    public bool AreExpressionsSame<T>(Expression<T>/*<Func<bool,bool,bool>>*/ expr1, Expression<T> expr2) {
        var expr1_reduced = expr1.Reduce();
        var expr2_reduced = expr2.Reduce();
        //at this point expr2_reduced is the same as it went it.
        return true;
    }


    public void AreExpressionSameShouldAcceptLambda() {
        ExpressionTest et = new ExpressionTest();

        et.AreExpressionsSame<Func<bool,bool,bool>>((a,b) => a || b, (a,b)=>a && b || b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking if a and b have the same boolean value

private bool Equals(bool a, bool b) {
  return !(a ^ b);
}

Answer (score 0):

Expressions `S1` and `S2` are equivalent, if `(S1 == S2)` is true for all `a, b` combinations. This tautology check can be implemented in `C#` as a truth-table enumeration as follows:

```
static bool S1(bool a, bool b)
{
    return a || b;
}

static bool S2(bool a, bool b)
{
    return (a && !b) || b;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool[] tf = { true, false };
    bool bSame = true;

    foreach(bool a in tf)
        foreach(bool b in tf)
        {
            bSame = bSame && (S1(a, b) == S2(a, b));
        }

    Console.WriteLine("S1 {0} S2", bSame ? "==" : "!=");
}
```